# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^p}}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^p}}$$
Converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, for $p>1$.

My approach: Let $\epsilon>1$ and $n_0\geq1$. Then, $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}{\left|\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^p}-\dfrac{\sin(mx)}{m^p}\right|}\leq \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{\left|\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^p}\right|+\left|\dfrac{\sin(mx)}{m^p}\right|\right\}\leq \dfrac{1}{n^p}+\dfrac{1}{m^p}\leq 2\epsilon$$

Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^p}}$ converges uniformly. This is correct?

Comment: I would say Weierstrass M makes easy work of this if you can use that result.

Comment: No, this 'proof' is not valid. You need to force the bound to hold for any $\epsilon > 0$; you can't start by taking $\epsilon > 1$ unless you later consider $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

That seems alright, though you should clarify that you're taking $n, m$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{n^p} + \frac{1}{m^p} \leq 2\epsilon$. Also, you should not restrict $\epsilon$ other than by asking it to be positive. Other than that, this seems fine.

Another way of approaching this, kind of similar but simpler, is the [Weierstraß M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test). Using this, you just have to observe that

$$
|f_n(x)| = |\frac{sin(xn)}{n^p}| \leq \frac{1}{n^p} \ , (\forall x \in \mathbb{R})
$$

and that if $p > 1$, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^p} < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_{n}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin(kx)}{k^{p}}$, if you want to go through with uniformly Cauchy test, it should look like this:

\begin{align*}
|S_{n}(x)-S_{m}(x)|&=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin(kx)}{k^{p}}\right|\leq\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{p}},
\end{align*}
you should be able to finish from here.

Comment: I believe those $n$ should be $k$

Comment: Yes, true, you are right.